# deleting nodes on basis of id in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, nodes

In this segment of my drupal program i have displayed the nodes on a page using a page callback function. Now what i need to do is delete nodes on basis of their ids.

I wish to do this by providing a 'Delete' link by the side of each displayed node. Can anyone help me with this? 
I am very new to Drupal. So a detailed answer would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
function mfrp_nodelist() {
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query
->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->entityCondition('bundle', 'article') //this part also confused me, is it bundle, type or both? bundle works for me
->propertyCondition('status', 1)
->propertyCondition('uid', '1');
$result = $query->execute();
$nids = array_keys($result['node']);
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
$output = node_view_multiple($nodes);
return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to create listing of node in drupal theme table and this code will work on cliking on delete Link

```
function yourmodule_rows() {
$rows = array()
$header = array(t('Sn no.'),t('Nid'),t('Node Title'),t('Op'),);
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
  $query->fields('n', array('title','nid'));
  $result = $query->execute();
  $sn = 0;
  while ($record = $result->fetchObject()) {
    $rows[] = array(++$sn, $record->nid, check_plain($record->title), l('Delete', 'node/'.$record->nid . '/delete'),);
}
  $render_array['yourmodule'] = array(array('#theme' => 'table', '#header' => $header, '#rows' => $rows, '#empty' => t('No Record found!'),), array('#theme' => 'pager',),);
  return $render_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick example in PHP of deleting a node trough an node ID.

```
   $nid= 22; // $node id , which needs to be retrieved from delete link but hardcoded for now;
   node_delete($nid);
```

You need to make a delete link that is something like this :

http://mydomain/nodes/delete?nid_delete=22

Then in PHP you can get that value through the PHP super global `filter_xss($_GET['nid_delete]);`

Comment: $nids = array_keys($result['node']);. Is $nids an array that holds the node ids of all nodes? If so, why cant I print the node ids using foreach loop?

Comment: for making the link according to your solution, I need the individual node ids. How do I mange to get those?

Comment: Can you share the output from your query?

Answer (score 0):

If you have views module, You can add a page(show them as grid or table) and list the article content (add the title, fields you need and delete link). By using the delete link you can delete the node(Make sure the user have permission to delete the node content type)

Comment: Can you kindly help me out with how to display them in the form of a list?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found a way to display my nodes in the form of list. And a delete link has also been created. However, I cannot understand how to make the link work. Which page to connect the link with and how to finally delete the nodes on the basis of the links? Any help will be appreciated.

```
function mfrp_nodelist() {
$output = array();
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query
->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->entityCondition('bundle', 'article') //this part also confused me, is it 
bundle, type or both? bundle works for me
->propertyCondition('status', 1)
->propertyCondition('uid', '1');
$result = $query->execute();
$nids = (array_keys($result['node']));
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

$nid=array();
foreach ($nodes as $nid){
$outputs[] = array('data' => array( $nid->nid, $nid->title, "<a 
href='delete/{$nid->nid}'>" . t('Delete') . "</a>"."|"."<a href='edit/{$nid-
>nid}'>" . t('Edit') . "</a>"));
}
dpm($output);
echo "The number of records are ".count($outputs); 

$per_page = 4;
// Initialize the pager
$current_page = pager_default_initialize(count($outputs), $per_page);
// Split your list into page sized chunks
$chunks = array_chunk($outputs, $per_page, TRUE);
// Show the appropriate items from the list
$header = array(t('nid'),t('title'));

$output = theme('table',
array('header' => $header,
'rows' => $chunks[$current_page],
'attributes' => array(),
'empty' => t("No records found")));
// Show the pager
$output .= theme('pager', array('quantity',count($outputs)));
//return $output .= theme('pager',array('quantity',count($rows)));
return theme('mfrp_list', array('results' => $output));
}
```